# Triple integral in cylindrical coordinates system

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multiple-integral

I have to evaluate the following triple integral:

$$\iiint_{V}(3z^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

where $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3,\ x^2+y^2\ge z^2,\ 0\le x^2+y^2\le \frac{1}{2}\}$

Passing to the cylindrical coordinates, I find out that $\ 0 \le \rho \le \frac{\sqrt2}{2},\ 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi,\ -\rho \le z \le \rho$ and the new integral will be $$\iiint_{V'}(3z^2+\rho^2\sin^2\theta)\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta\,dz$$

I'm not so sure how to solve this. Is it the product of three simple integrals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't the product of $3$ simple integrals, as the boundary conditions of $z$ depend on $\rho$.

We can evaluate this as -
\begin{align}
\iiint_{V'}(3z^2+\rho^2\sin^2\theta)\rho d\rho d\theta dz &= 
\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}\int_{-\rho}^{\rho}\int_0^{2\pi}(3z^2+\rho^2\sin^2\theta)\rho d\theta dz d\rho \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}\int_{-\rho}^{\rho}(6\pi z^2+\pi\rho^2)\rho dz d\rho \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}(4\pi \rho^3+2\pi\rho^3)\rho d\rho \\
&= \frac{3\pi}{10\sqrt 2}
\end{align}